# HTTP Authentication Headers for IIS windows authentication

Tags: iphone, iis, http-authentication

I have a web site hosted on IIS with windows authentication. I am trying to access it in one  of my iPhone web application. Presently i am using this code, but it is not working.

NSString *authString = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", @"myusername", @"mypassword"]dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] base64Encoding];

```
authString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Basic %@", authString];

**[requestObj setValue:authString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];**
```

my web app is hosted with windows authentication. but here i am using basic. can any one post what is the correct http header for it.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the main difference is you need to specify the domain you are authenticating against as well as the username and password. Something like this should work. I've used a synchronous request for brevity, ideally you should use an ASINetworkQueue or NSOperationQueue to perform the request.

```
NSString *username = @"test";
NSString *password = @"test";
NSString *domain = @"test";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setUseSessionPersistence:YES];
[request setUsername:username];
[request setPassword:password];
[request setDomain:domain];
[request start];
if ([request error]) {
    if ([[request error] code] == ASIAuthenticationErrorType) {
        //Authentication failed
    }
} else {
    NSLog([request responseString]);
}
```

I don't have access to a Windows server to test this, but I have tested NTLM in the past so it should work... :)

Comment: Thanks Pokeb...

It is working fine...thaanks a lot....but i need to play a video from windows server. But MPMovieplayerController is not supporting any authentication mechanism. What to do???

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController only supports loading media via the standard NSURL* methods. Your best bet is to add additional supported authentication types at the server, but as a last resort you could create a loopback HTTP server running on the device to proxy the data between NSURLConnection and the NTLM-authenticated server.

Comment: The example won't print any output to the log as it is asynchronous - when `[request responseString]` is evaluated there's a good chance that the request is still processing.  However, the rest of it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Windows authentication (NTLM) isn't as simple as basic authentication.  NTLM requires more than one webrequest to negotiate the security so there isn't a static HTTP header you can send to log in.

Comment: Switching to use basic authentication would be the easiest solution.

Comment: but my enterprise app is already hosted one...i cant chage the authentication type...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the third-party [ASIHTTPRequest library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to perform NTLM over HTTP authentication.

Comment: Hi...

Can you post me some code how to do NTLM auth with ASIHTTPRequest.

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure it supports NTLM Authentication but have you investigated the `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` method on the NSUrlConnection?

Comment: yea...i checked didReceivedAuthenticationChallenge method. it is working fine to download data. but i am trying to play a video. with MPMoviePlayerController it is not working well.